# JQuery and ASP NET - Bootstrap Select is not automatically picking up the value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am using `ASP NET MVC` and `Bootstrap Select` plugin. The problem I have is that I am trying to see if one of the values that I have in a `List` is equal to some other value that I have in a `View` and then if it is, it has to make that `option` selected in `<select>` tag.
This does not work. The code itself runs perfectly fine when I manually choose the value but I want it to be choosed immediately when someone opens the page, because this `<select>` tag is inside the **form** so it would be much easier for the users to have that automatically selected.

This is what I mean by this:

#### View

```
<div class="component">
<select id="vehicle-select" class="selectpicker form-control" title="Select Product Type">
     @foreach (var item in productType)
          {
             if (item["Name"] == vehicleNamePage)
                 {
                    selected = "selected";
                 }
               else
                  {
                    selected = "";
                  }
                  <option @selected value="@item["SF Type"],@item["Form Key"]">
                     @item["Name"]
                  </option>
            }
   </select>
 </div>
```

And it does show on the page the selected value but it is not selected, because when I press the submit button the validation says it is not selected.

#### jQuery

```
 $body.on('vehicle-type:selected', function (event, json) {

                var vehicleField = json.vehicleType.split(',');
                searchType = vehicleField[0];

                $body.trigger('dealer-locator:hide');
                $body.find('#accordion').attr("data-vehicle", vehicleField[1]);
                if ($countryDropdown.selectpicker('val')) {
                    search(zip, searchType, country);
                }
            });
```

The **form** will only work when I manually select something not when I automatically put something as a selected option.

Is this something that can be done?

Comment: I think you have need to mention your select `id` correctly: `$body.on('#vehicle-type:selected', function (event, json) {`

Comment: @RahulSharma Thank you for the answer, but does not fix the issue. This function will only be triggered once I change the vehicle-type but manually

Comment: Can you show the code when you are submitting your data? What is the problem that you are encountering?

Comment: @RahulSharma The code is up there. It just shows the error that it is not selected "the product type is not selected"

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $("#vehicle-select").find(":selected").trigger('change');
})
    
$("#vehicle-select").change(function(){
  console.log("Something happend")
})
```